# Spark/Zeppelin: Issue with showing data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I'm having an issue trying to show data that's in my DF.(or more generally put, i want to visualize the data. Preferably with the SQL interperter)
I've gotten a flat text file (log excerpt) that i'm formatting through a class and then creating a DF based on the result.

The data itself looks like this (single line excerpt) :

```
2017-02-09 15:56:15,411 INFO [pool-2-thread-1] n.t.f.c.LoggingConsumer [LoggingConsumer.java:27] [Floor=b827eb074534, tile=00051] Data received: '[false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true]', batch size= 0
```

Here's my code:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import java.net.URL
import java.nio.charset.Charset
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import sqlContext.implicits._

val realdata = sc.textFile("/root/application.txt")

case class testClass(date: String, time: String, level: String, unknown1: String, unknownConsumer: String, unknownConsumer2: String, vloer: String, tegel: String, msg: String, sensor1: String, sensor2: String, sensor3: String, sensor4: String, sensor5: String, sensor6: String, sensor7: String, sensor8: String, batchsize: String, troepje1: String, troepje2: String)

val mapData = realdata
.filter(line => line.contains("data") && line.contains("INFO"))
.map(s => s.split(" ").toList)
.map(
s => testClass(s(0),
s(1).split(",")(0),
s(1).split(",")(1),
s(3),
s(4),
s(5),
s(6),
s(7),
s(8),
s(15),
s(16),
s(17),
s(18),
s(19),
s(20),
s(21),
s(22),
"",
"",
""
)
).toDF
```

When i print the resulting schema it seems to do what i want:

```
 root
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- level: string (nullable = true)
 |-- unknown1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- unknownConsumer: string (nullable = true)
 |-- unknownConsumer2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- vloer: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tegel: string (nullable = true)
 |-- msg: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sensor1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sensor2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sensor3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sensor4: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sensor5: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sensor6: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sensor7: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sensor8: string (nullable = true)
 |-- batchsize: string (nullable = true)
 |-- troepje1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- troepje2: string (nullable = true)
```

Now granted, it's not very pretty (and i do apologise for the dutch) but that seems to work.

But when i do a mapData.show or anything like that i get:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3, localhost, executor driver): java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2024)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.downloadFile(Utils.scala:503)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:639)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:463)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:508)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:500)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:99)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:500)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:257)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1931)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1944)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:333)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2371)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2765)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2370)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2377)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2113)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2112)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedCallback(Dataset.scala:2795)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2112)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2327)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:248)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:636)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:595)
  ... 56 elided
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
  at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
  at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2024)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.downloadFile(Utils.scala:503)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:639)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:463)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:508)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:500)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:99)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:500)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:257)
  ... 3 more
```

Is there anybody that can tell me what i'm doing wrong or if there's a better way to visualize the data ?

Thank you so much for any help or guidance.

Comment: The data file you are reading doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks, i verified the existance of the file and it does exist on that location and has full permissions. Could this be an issue with tmp files ? I did have issues with that earlier where my spark session could not create a folder in /tmp.

Comment: The presence of `createTempFile` in the stack trace makes it almost certain that you do have a problem with temporary files. Something is seriously wrong with your runtime environment.